# Query metadata in Azure VM

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2, metadata, azure-virtual-machine

What is the best way in Azure for a VM to query whether it is running in Azure vs AWS? How can you get other metadata such as instance type (size)?
In AWS EC2, you can query http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data/ inside a VM to get its metadata (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Metadata Service provided by Azure:

```
curl -H Metadata:true "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-08-01"
```

For futher detailed api paths, you can visit:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service

Answer (score 0):

You can use BGInfo tool for windows platform.
run cmd from cmd.exe
bgifo.exe  /rtf:

Answer (score 0):

The In-VM Metadata service allows a standard method to pull the maintenance status of that VM by executing the command:

curl http://169.254.169.254/metadata/v1/maintenance

Answer (score 0):

Azure does not currently expose instance metadata inside a VM, and Microsoft is aware that people would like this feature: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/6204911-provide-virtual-machine-instance-metadata-support